# Generating an html report after a series of steps are done in C#

Tags: c#, .net, html, .net-3.5, report

I'm stuck at this, I just did a little deployment tool that works like this:

- Grabs an msi installer and installs it
- Copies all the config files to be modified afterwards
- Once all the files are modified the deployment tool is ran again, it copies all the files and restarts the IIS server if necessary

Last Friday I was told that I should generate an html report indicating that each step was completed successfully, I hand crafted the html file like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Project Deployment Report</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <div id="main">

    <h1>Project Deployment Report - {DATE}</h1>
    <br />
    <h2>First Run</h2>
    <p>This will report when the Project Deployment tool is run with "-f" parameter, this will copy all
    the configuration files to be modified afterwards</p>

    <table class ="one-column-emphasis">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="oce-first">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Project Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Install for the first time</th>
            <th scope="col">Copy Original Config files</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{PROJECT NAME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{PROJECT NAME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{PROJECT NAME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <br />
    <h2>Copy Configuration Run</h2>
    <p></p>

    <table class ="one-column-emphasis">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="oce-first">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Project Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Install for the first time</th>
            <th scope="col">Copy Original Config files</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lookup Service</td>
            <td>Correct</td>
            <td>Correct</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{PROJECT NAME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{PROJECT NAME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
            <td>{POSSIBLE OUTCOME}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I got a singleton logger that at the same time acts as a Subject and there are two subscribers a `ConsoleLogger` and a `HtmlLogger`.

My problem and my question is how to interpret the log when information is "pushed" down to the Html logger and once there how to fill the html report.

The idea I had was to create a class or structure with a list of project names and they possible outcomes but I don't see how to fill the html report that I have.

Any ideas or comments on this?

Thanks, regards!

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way of generating html reports it to actually fill an XML document, then transform the resulting XML into HTML via XSL.

Its much easier to fill on the fly, and its easier to change the output formatting down the line as well.

Comment: do you have a link to a tutorial or an example? Thanks Jon!

Comment: This codeproject walkthrough has a fairly simple stylesheet that could be a basis. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XML_to_HTML_Convertor.aspx